# dynamic if condition comparison of variables in javascript

Tags: javascript

I've 3 variables a,b,c

The initial values of this variables will be 'false'

I want to compare this variables only have that 'true' value.

For example,

```
a=true,b=false,c=true.
```

So I need to compare like,

```
if(a && c)

if, a=true,b=true,c=true,

if(a && b && c)
```

How can I generate this if condition dynamically?

Comment: Are you looking to generate a string representation of the JavaScript code for that if condition?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically? You can't (or shouldn't) generate code at runtime, there is almost always a better way.

Comment: If all variables you want, for example `b` and `c`, are `true`, what's the meaning of writing `if (b && c) {...`? since this clause will always pass.

Comment: sorry, I had a mistake. Now I corrected the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you could approach the issue with [`[].every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) which performs a similar comparison:

```
if ([a, b, c].every(Boolean)) {
    // etc.
}
```

*Here, `Boolean()` is a native function that will accept a value and return its boolean value.*

That said, just this will cover all cases too, considering that it uses short circuiting to stop the comparison once a `false` value is found and is undoubtedly easier to read:

```
if (a && b && c) {
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: No need for `isTrue` - the `Boolean` function can do that for you - `[a, b, c].every(Boolean)`